# R selecting rows by conditions given in an external table

Tags: r

Given the following data

```
data_min <- data.frame("cond"=c("a","b","c"),"min"=c(1,3,1))
data <- data.frame("cond"=c("a","b","b","a","c"),"val"=c(0,2,4,7,0))
```

I would like to select all rows from `data` for that the value in `val` is bigger than the minimum value specified in `data_min` for that condidition. Thus, in the given example, I expect to end up with a table

```
cond val
b    4
a    7
```

So far, I have tried

```
datanew <- data[which(data$cond==data_min$cond & data$val > data_min$min),]
```

which gives me `a 7`but not `b 4`. I have two questions, (1) why do I get the result I get, and (2) how do I get the desired result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `match` because the data.frames have different numbers of rows:

`data[data_min[match(data$cond, data_min$cond),]$min  <= data$val,]`

Comment: Nice one. Will try one more way after this.

Comment: Great that works! I will close the question by tomorrow in order to give more people a chance to respond. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You could just merge the two data frames together to make things easier:

```
> m=merge(data,data_min,by='cond')
> m[which(m$val > m$min), c('cond','val')]
  cond val
2    a   7
4    b   4
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `dplyr`. We can perform a join first and then filter the condition between the `val` and `min` column.

```
library(dplyr)

data2 <- data %>%
  left_join(data_min, by = "cond") %>%
  filter(val > min) %>%
  select(-min)
data2
  cond val
1    b   4
2    a   7
```